# Frequented or frequented to?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it grammatically incorrect to use "frequented to"?

Answer (score 2):

If by *to* you mean the preposition of place, then no, as a brief look at the Ngram viewer will tell you. You can say 1a below, but not 1b:

> **[1a]** I frequented the local bar more than I cared to admit.
>   **[1b]** *I **frequented to** the local bar more than I cared to admit.

The place so frequented must be a direct object.

But *frequented* licenses an infinitive of purpose. From [*Sickle Cell Disease/Sickle Cell Trait: The Triumphant Struggle of One Man*](https://books.google.com/books?id=eXxikrMcjj4C&pg=PA209&dq=%22frequented%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip38_uwcrPAhWFNT4KHVK-CU84PBDoAQghMAE#v=onepage&q=%22frequented%20to%22&f=false) by E. Stanley:

> There was a juice bar not too far from away, which I **frequented to** get a 16-ounce glass of carrot juice.